# Visual Studio checkout from TFS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

This question is about Visual Studio and Team Foundation Server ( TFS ). Im a novice with TFS and got a bit confused over a thing.

If I have connected to a TFS-project through VS and have all the code in VS. If I start editing a file I see a message like "foo.cs has been automatically checked out for editing." Does other people in the project see that? I just want to test things locally and dont want to affect other people in the project.

I am also a bit confused about that it says that is " has been automatically checked out for editing". I mean I already see the code in VS so I thought I had already checked it out.

I am used to work with SVN and haven't really worked with TFS before but in SVN you have to check out the code to be able to see it in your IDE of choice.

Comment: Just an SVN <=> TFS terminology clarification. "SVN: check-out read-only" == "TFS: Get Latest".  "SVN: check-out read-write" == "TFS: Check out for Edit".  Getting a read-only copy does not put a lock on the file, so no one else sees that you have a copy.  Getting a read-write copy puts the lock on so others see that you have it "checked out (for editing)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, other people will see that you checked out the file. They will still be able to edit it. There is a setting in Tool -> Options -> Version Control not to check out files automatically.

Comment: Just to clarify. They see that the file is checked out, they don't see the message you are seeing. Also the file is not checked out just because you open it up and look at it. It is only automatically checked out if you edit the file. You can look at it and read it all you want without checking it out. Also depending on your TFS configuration others may or may not be able to modify it if you have it checked out. TFS lets you put an exclusive lock on a file when checked out, just depends how you have it configured.

Comment: No such option in VS2012 / TFS.

Comment: In VS2012/TFS, the option is called "Tools / Options / Source Control / Environment / Checked-in Items / Editing == Check out automatically"

Comment: This is not a solution to my problem.  I opened a solution with no files checked out.  I didn't edit any file and yet one file was automatically checked out for me by VS without my intention.  I do not know why this behavior happens but I would like to stop it.  The above suggestions do not correct this issue.